Flex Container with Scrollable Content
I have a flex container in which I want to have another flex container which scrolls content when it is too large to fit the screen. This is what I have so far:
<Box
    sx={{
        m: 'var(--Content-margin)',
        p: 'var(--Content-padding)',
        width: 'var(--Content-width)',
        flex: 1,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
    }}
>
    <Box sx={{ flex: 1, overflow: 'scroll', backgroundColor: 'orange' }}>
        ... // long list of content
    </Box>
</Box>

I have tried playing around with all parameters but it does not work. It always adds the browser default scrolling and content just grows downwards.
Currently looks like the following. As you can see, the scrolling is on the browser level and not on the orange box:


You need to give the overflowing container a fixed max-height. If you do not, it will not overflow, it will grow

there is no height set anywhere, is there ?

No, there is nothing with fixed heights

You need to add a height to the orange box which fits the screen size. That way, the orange box won't be bigger than the screen and the overflow will work.
<Box
   sx={{ flex: 1, overflow: 'scroll', backgroundColor: 'orange', height: 'the height you want' }}
>
   // long list of content
</Box>



The orange box is not the screen size. On the screenshot you can see a nav bar at the top.

Sorry, as you said "which scrolls content when it is too large to fit the screen", I immediately thought about that. But if you know the height of the navbar, you can subscract it to the 100vh height. I will edit my answer and just put "the height you want" so it's not confusing.

This is hacky. I do not want to work with any kind of absolute values.

Alrighty then, but you'll need to set a height / max-height in order to make the overflow work.

The easiest way I know to fix this issue is to use flexbox with a height of 100% in the main container, this way it will adapt the height of the container to 100% of the screen size excluding the height of the nav.
I added an example here https://codepen.io/mariajunqueira/pen/gONRveV
html, body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

